# Attempt to call getDuration in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=1

Tags: android

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.widget.SeekBar;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.Map;

    /**
     * Created by Rahul-PC on 28-02-2017.
     */

    public class ApplozicAudioManager implements MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
        private static ApplozicAudioManager myObj;
        public ApplozicDocumentView currentView;
        Map<String, MediaPlayer> pool = new HashMap<>();
        Context context;
        int maxsize = 5;
        String TAG = "ApplozicAudioManager";
        String audio_duration;
        int hours, minute, second, duration;

        private ApplozicAudioManager() {

        }

        public static ApplozicAudioManager getInstance() {
            try {
                if (myObj == null) {
                    myObj = new ApplozicAudioManager();
                }
                return myObj;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        void play(Uri uri, final ApplozicDocumentView view) {
            final String key = view.message.getKeyString();
            MediaPlayer mp = pool.get(key);
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                    return;
                } else {
                    mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition());
                    mp.start();
                }
            } else {
                mp = new MediaPlayer();
                if (pool.size() >= maxsize) {
                    Map.Entry<String, MediaPlayer> entry = pool.entrySet().iterator().next();
                    String first = entry.getKey();
                    pool.remove(first);
                }
                pool.put(key, mp);
            }
            pauseOthersifPlaying();
            try {
                if (context != null && context.getContentResolver() !=null) {
                    mp.setDataSource(context, uri);
                    mp.prepare();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
            if (currentView != null) {
                currentView.setAudioIcons();
            }
            this.currentView = view;
            mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    mp.release();
                    pool.remove(key);
                    currentView.setAudioIcons();
                }
            });
            currentView.audioseekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if (fromUser) {
                        getMediaPlayer(key).seekTo(progress);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        public void pauseOthersifPlaying() {
            MediaPlayer m;
            Iterator it = pool.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                {
                    m = (MediaPlayer) pair.getValue();
                    if (m.isPlaying()) {
                        m.pause();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        int getAudioState(String key) {
            MediaPlayer mp = pool.get(key);
            if (mp != null) {
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    return 1;
                }
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }

        public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(String key) {
            return pool.get(key);
        }

        public void audiostop() {
            MediaPlayer temp;
            Iterator it = pool.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
                {
                    temp = (MediaPlayer) pair.getValue();
                    temp.stop();
                    temp.release();
                }
            }
            pool.clear();
        }

        public String refreshAudioDuration(String filePath) {
            MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                duration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                duration = duration / 1000;
                hours = duration / 3600;
                minute = duration / 60;
                second = duration % 60;
                mediaPlayer.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            audio_duration = hours + "" + minute + ":" + second;
            return audio_duration;
        }

    }
```

I got below error in android 7 my code work fine on android 6 or earlier 
suggest any solution
If i initialize Media Player Object in Activity as static and further use in service class then its show me this  error (-38, 0) , Attempt to perform seekTo in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurrentState=0 , start called in state 0.

```
E/MediaPlayer: Attempt to call getDuration in wrong state: mPlayer=0x0, mCurren`enter code here`tState=1
03-15 18:27:19.695 2020-2020/com.mobicomkit.sample E/MediaPlayer: error (-38, 0)
03-15 18:27:19.711 2020-2020/com.mobicomkit.sample E/MediaPlayer: Error (-38,0)
03-15 18:27:19.713 2020-2020/com.mobicomkit.sample I/statee:: -1
```

Comment: I recommend you look at the state diagram, and never have more than one instance of `MediaPlayer` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: Actually i am implementing chat application where there is multiple audio file are and i am trying  to play one at a time and pause other if any one is playing .and interesting things is it work below android 7 .but it did not work on android 7

Comment: it also show "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.ContentResolver android.content.Context.getContentResolver()' on a null object reference"